# Create index for DBMS_COMPARISON package error ORA-23629 : is not an eligible index

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to a comparison between two tables which are present on same DB using below create_comparison procedure

```
begin  
dbms_comparison.create_comparison(  
   comparison_name => 'comp_dbms_test',  
   SCHEMA_NAME => 'DEV06_OWNER',  
  OBJECT_NAME => 'facility_prod_temp',  
   INDEX_SCHEMA_NAME => 'DEV06_OWNER',  
  INDEX_NAME => 'idx_test',  
  dblink_name => null,  
  REMOTE_SCHEMA_NAME => 'DEV06_OWNER',  
   remote_object_name => 'facility_test_temp',  
   column_list => '*',  
  SCAN_MODE => DBMS_COMPARISON.CMP_SCAN_MODE_FULL);  
end;
```

and getting below error --

```
Error report:  
ORA-23629: DEV06_OWNER.IDX_TEST is not an eligible index on table DEV06_OWNER.FACILITY_PROD_TEMP for comparison
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_COMPARISON", line 5008
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_COMPARISON", line 448
```

Here is the structure of the table :

```
desc FACILITY_PROD_TEMP;  

Name                Null Type                 
------------------- ---- ------------------   
PARTITION_KEY            VARCHAR2(12)         
CONTRACT_REFERENCE       VARCHAR2(101 CHAR)   
CONTRACT_DESC            VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)   
ATTRIBUTE_3              VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)   
ATTRIBUTE_1              VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)   
COMMITED                 VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)    
ATTRIBUTE_6              VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)   
ATTRIBUTE_7              VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)   
ATTRIBUTE_8              VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)   
VALUE_DATE               VARCHAR2(30)         
ATTRIBUTE_5              VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)   
LGD                      VARCHAR2(30)         
DIM16                    VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)   
MATURITY_DATE            VARCHAR2(50)         
DIM9                     VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)   
IMPORT_SOURCE            VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
```

I have created a index on contract_reference column using below syntax -

```
 create index idx_test on facility_prod_temp (contract_reference);
```

Oracle Doc says :

For the scan modes CMP_SCAN_MODE_FULL and CMP_SCAN_MODE_CUSTOM to be supported, the database objects must have one of the following types of indexes:
•A single-column index on a number, timestamp, interval, DATE, VARCHAR2, or CHAR data type column

According to which I have created a index on CONTRACT_REFERENCE   column which is of varchar2 type.

I am using -

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: ORA-23629: DEV06_OWNER.IDX_TEST is not an eligible index on table DEV06_OWNER.FACILITY_PROD_TEMP for comparison
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_COMPARISON", line 5008
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_COMPARISON", line 448

Comment: this is the actual error maybe a typo :)

Comment: Please don't use comments to add or correct information in the question. Instead, you should edit the question to make whatever changes are needed. I've done it this time - in future please keep this in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you read a bit further in [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_comparison.htm#CHDFBEJI), it says

```
The index columns in a comparison must uniquely identify every row involved in 
a comparison. The following constraints satisfy this requirement:

- A primary key constraint
- A unique constraint on one or more non-NULL columns
```

So you'll need to add either a primary key or a unique constraint to the contract_reference column:

```
alter table facility_prod_temp add constraint uk_fpt_temp unique (contract_reference);
```

Then you can use that constraint's index (which shares the same name by default) in your dbms_comparison call:

```
INDEX_NAME => 'uk_fpt_temp',
```

Comment: I tried using unique constraint but it gives me same error and one more thing that I forgot to mention is that contract_reference column is containing NULL values so I cannot create a primary key on it !